# MySQL Error 1822: Failed to add foreign key constraint; missing index for contraint BUT index exists

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling, foreign-keys

I am trying to add an foreign key to my flightschedule table but it fails, but I do not really know why. The foreign key should reference the txtAC_tag attribute from the tblAircraft table which is part of the Primary key!
So the tblAircraft is indexed (the primary key is a combined key which consists of idAC and txtAC_tag -> could a combined Primary key be the problem?) and the attribute's datatype do match.

Here are my table declarations and the foreign key declarations:

```
create table if not exists tblAircrafts(
idAC       int not null auto_increment,
txtAC_tag  varchar(255) not null,
txtAC_type varchar(255) not null,
primary key(idAC, txtAC_tag));

create table if not exists tblFlightSchedule(
ID int not null auto_increment,
datDate date,
txtFrom varchar(255),
txtTo   varchar(255),
txtFlight varchar(255),
numFlight_time_decimal decimal(4,2),
txtAC_tag varchar(255) not null,
txtAC_type varchar(255) not null,
numSeatCapacity int unsigned,
numLoad int unsigned, -- auslastung 
numDirt decimal(20,19),
numTotalFlightTime decimal(50,5),
numCumDirt decimal(20,15),
primary key(ID));

alter table tblflightschedule
add foreign key(txtAC_tag) references tblaircrafts(txtAC_tag);
```

And here is the ERROR message:

```
Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constaint. Missing index for constraint '' in the referenced table 'tblaircrafts'
```

Any suggestions? I appreciate any kind of help you can give me, thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
add foreign key(txtAC_tag) references tblaircrafts(txtAC_tag);
```

here you are binding `txtAC_tag` to `txtAC_tag` of `tblaircrafts` table in a foreign key relationship but in `tblaircrafts` the column `txtAC_tag` is neither `unique` nor `primary` that's why it is showing error.

For foreign key relationship, the parent table column on which you are creating relation must be `unique` or `primary` and they must have the same `datatype` and `size` also.

To resolve this make `txtAC_tag` column unique.

Comment: ...and so therefore he should probably make `txtAC_tag` unique using a constraint +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes, you are saying the exact thing.

Comment: In MySQL 8, the order on how the composite keyscolumns is specified and referenced has to be the same.

Comment: This worked for me on MySQL 8.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have created **Composite Primary Key** for the table **tblAircrafts**.

If you wanted to add the composite key reference to the table **tblflightschedule**, you need to use the below syntax:

```
alter table tblflightschedule
add foreign key ('int Column', txtAC_tag) references tblaircrafts **(idAC, txtAC_tag);**
```

**And you have to refer two columns for adding foreign key ('int Column', txtAC_tag).**

So you can either add one more column in your **tblflightschedule** table or drop one column from **tblaircrafts** table.